# Help with logic in the Proof of √2 exists

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone explain why A > B and B < C get us A > C?

This is the Proof for the existence of √2 and I understand every other part of the proof including why we want B < C so that we can use the Archimedean Property of R and also why we want A > C so that it eventually leads to a contradiction but I don’t see how the logic of the implications would work out!

[image]
Thank you very much!

Here is the full proof in case anyone wants to see it

[image]

Comment: It’s not $A > B$ and $B < C$ implying $A > C$.  You have $A > x^2-B$ and $B < x^2 - 2$ implying $A > 2$.

Comment: Yea, but how do they know that A > 2 which is derived from A > x^2 - C when B < C?

Comment: $B < x^2 - 2$ is the same as $-B > 2-x^2$.  So $A > x^2 - B > x^2 + (2-x^2) = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, I also see this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can look at it is the following:
$$
\left(x - \tfrac{1}{m}\right)^2 > x^2 - \frac{2x}{m} = x^2 + \underbrace{\left(-\frac{2x}{m} + (x^2 - 2)\right)}_{> 0} - (x^2 - 2) > x^2 - (x^2 - 2)
$$
where the term in brackets is > 0 by the assumption B < C

Comment: The first inequality you meant (x- 1/m)^2 instead of (x^2 -1/m)^2

Comment: Thank you, that makes so much sense!

Comment: Ah thanks, fixed that.